# Wi-Fi working but Bluetooth is not working on Dell Vostro 3350

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, broadcom

I have just installed latest version of ubuntu on my laptop Dell Vostro 3350
and my Wi-Fi works just fine, but the Bluetooth is not working or detected at all.

Below a screenshot from my laptop:

[image: Wireless & Bluetooth & driver manager]

Result after running `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
[    0.214235] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.291902] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   47.801460] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[  164.241397] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[  180.113487] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[  385.969376] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
```

Result for `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 413c:818d Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6484 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please be specific; latest means what?  Ubuntu 21.04 Desktop?  (or the 2021-April release of desktop)

Comment: Have you tried selecting the proprietary driver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: am using ubuntu 20.04.2, and i have tried installing broadcom drivers for my wifi card [14e4:4315] (rev 01) but it's Bluetooth is not working while wifi works just fine :(

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: i have included the result :) thank you for responding to my question , this is frustrating

Comment: Can you add results for `lsusb` as I didn't see what I expected

Comment: done i included it , let me know if you need anything else :)